# Как правильно задать расположение кластеров на контурной карте России в проекции Ламберта?

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api

Изучаю потихоньку api карт и столкнулся с проблемой на проекции Ламберта:

```
https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsbox/2.1/lambert_map/
```

ссылка на codepen: `https://codepen.io/nookat/pen/mdqOLdO`

Отдельные метки отображаются хорошо, в нужном месте, а вот кластерам нужен я так понимаю метод fromGlobalPixels, реализации которого нету. Из за этого они отображаются в [0, 0]. Как бы можно это сделать? Ломаю голову, а мысля не приходит как преобразовать глобальные пиксели в координаты проекции. Может кто то сталкивался с таким.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: То есть вы хотите довольно старую (насколько мне известно) и не самую стабильную и удобную реализацию кластеризатора заставить работать ещё и в не предназначенной для него проекции? Может тогда уже сразу свою версию кластеризатора как-нибудь реализовать? Из каких-то тестовых наработок в этом направлении видится только https://jsfiddle.net/flapenguin/ohvfc4ks/1/ , основанный, кажется, на d3-geo https://github.com/d3/d3-geo

Comment: @YaCor' Я хочу найти реализацию метода fromGlobalPixels, тогда все заведется и будет нормально. Но из за того, что его нет, то как то все печально. Странно как то все получается) Такое ощущение, что никто и никогда не поворачивал в такую проекцию. Я думал она популярная, но че то никто походу не юзает